# limitation on SQL where clause using OR

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL request like:

```
select X from "myTable" where (cond1 AND cond2) OR (cond3 AND cond 4)...
```

How many (cond AND cond) can I have in my clause where? Because it makes a stackOverFlow error with my `24578` conditions.

final List update = xService.getCountUpdate(couple);

couple is a list build by that way (every line in my file this is done ):

```
dcIssn = new ArrayList<String>();

dcIssn.add(0, row.getCell(dc).getStringCellValue());
dcIssn.add(1, row.getCell(issn).getStringCellValue());

couple.add(dcIssn);
```

Comment: are you serious 24578 conditions?

Comment: Wait.. You mean 24578 connections? What makes you to use that much number of conditions.. It'll greatly affect DB performance IMO..

Comment: If you have 24578 conditions you should really re-think your code and change it to be more efficient.

Comment: Anyway, depending on the database, the maximum amount of parameters in a query should be typically around 64k, so that should still be doable (not efficient, though). StackOverflow doesn't sound like the database making problems anyway. Code?

Comment: that's whats I'm trying but this is a function for an import and I'm trying on this file but it can be greater than that so I think I have to cut my List in sub-list to improve a litlle

Comment: I'm using SQL server

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem.

The problem was not my query, just my StringBuilder which was too short for the query. 
Thank you for helping me =)

Answer (score -1):

There is no limit to the number of predicates that can be included in a search condition. For more information about search conditions and predicates.

see this:-
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx